# Want to Change 'wp-content' path of WordPress site hosted in IIS

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site hosted in IIS. WordPress hosted server is running in AWS under auto scaling. So theme or plugin file changes which saves in server will not be there in new server added to auto scaling group if scaling occurs. So I was looking to change the `wp-content` path of WordPress site to some other URLs which is hosted in different server.

I'm able to change the `wp-content` path by adding the below variable in `wp-config.php` file an the site will work.

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/blog/wp-content' );
```

But If I change the `wp-content` path to 'URL' by adding the below variables in `wp-config.php` file,it is not working - `wp-content` path will take from WordPress hosted root dirctory.

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example/blog/wp-content' );
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'http://example/blog/wp-content/plugins' );
```

So please help me to change the WordPress content path to 'URL' rather than 'directory'. I've been checking for a solution for the last 2 weeks.

Comment: Hi, please fix the formatting on your post, thank you.

Comment: Why don't you make the changes inside the DB (table should be `wp_options`, if I'm not mistaken)? If that is not an option for some reason, try to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Answer (score 0):

Its resolved now.We have hosted word-press in a single server and made URL redirection in LB.